# How to get friend's feed using Instagram Graph API or Instagram Basic Display API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

After one day instagram [will disable Legacy API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2019/10/15/launch-instagram-basic-display-api/). There will be two official ways to access Instagram data - [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) with `graph.facebook.com` base and the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/) with `api.instagram.com` and `graph.instagram.com` url bases.

How to get friend's profile feed with new ways ?

Seems like old way was `GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent`

I tried `GET https://graph.instagram.com/{user-id}/media?fields=id,caption&access_token={access_koken}` endpoint but I got following error:

> {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Object with ID
>   '{user-id}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
>   permissions, or does not support this
>   operation","type":"IGApiException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"AfL9LNy4QaaNREWCjgNBEFW"}}

Comment: its very likely you just didn't request enough permissions when the app launches

Comment: I think it's enough permissions, I authorized with `scope=user_profile,user_media`

Answer (score 0):

I presume you did replace {user-id} with an actual user id ? Generally speaking you can use the word "me" in it's place.

`https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption&access_token=<your access token>`

If your application was an old Instagram "client" app then I *think* that it will no longer work after the deadline. We have had to create a new Instagram app via a Facebook application (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

From there you can add "Products" and "Instagram" is one of those products. You have to go through an app review having requested "instagram_user_profile" and "instagram_user_media" in order to start using the app in live mode, but you can add testers whilst you are developing it. This is found via the "Basic Display" link (under the Instagram product) where you will also find you app id and secret.

[image: Facebook with Instagram Product]